# Why are unchanged rows updated?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

EF updates rows even though they remain unchanged. I can't understand this behavior. There are two DB Models involved: Day and Activity (relation 1-1). The code is simplified to make things more clear.

```
public class Day
{
    [Key]
    public int DayId { get; set; }
    ...
    public Activity? Activity { get; set; } //Day may or may not have an activity
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}

public class Activity
{
    [Key]
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public int DayId { get; set; } //Foreign key
    public int Property { get; set; }
    ...
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Data is then being retrieved from DB in a single context:

```
List<Day> GetDays(...)
{
    ctx = _factory.CreateDbContext(); //Global attribute 
    
    return from day in ctx.Days.Where(day => ...conditions...)
                     .Include(x => x.Activity)
                     select day).ToList();
}
```

Data is processed:

```
List<Day> list = GetDays(...);

foreach(Day other_day in some_other_day_list)
{
list.Single(day => day.DayId == other_day.DayId).Activity.Property = other_day.Activity.Property;
}

SaveDates(list);
```

Data is Saved:

```
SaveDates(List<Day> list)
{
    ctx.Days.UpdateRange(list); //ctx is global attribute
    ctx.SaveChanges();
    ctx.Dispose();
}
```

The result of this operation is that ALL Days are being updated (RowVersion is changed) and ONLY the modified Activities of each Day are being updated. All Days are updated despite the fact that only some of Days have modified Activities. I can't google the answer, or I don't know the right question to ask.

Comment: See [DbContext.UpdateRange Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.updaterange?view=efcore-6.0). It says: *"Begins tracking the given entities and entries reachable from the given entities using the Modified state by default [...]"*. Drop this line!

Comment: OMG off course - thank you!